# Remove key from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I currently have a problem with removing a key in a hashmap. I created a hashmap within a hashmap. I need to remove a key by the value inside the hashmap within the hashmap. So the hashmap looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> people_attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> people = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

If I try to remove a key, replace `remove_name.add(p_name)` with `people.remove(p_name)` I get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.
Right now, I use an arraylist to add the keys that needs to be remove, then loop through the arraylist to remove the keys from the hashmap.

So far this is the solution:

```
for(String p_name : people.keySet()) { // search through people with attribute
   for(String p_attributes : people.get(p_name).keySet()) { // search through attributes map
       if(p_attributes.equals(g_att)) { // when current attributes equal to guess attribute
          p_value = people.get(p_name).get(p_attributes);
             if(!p_value.equals(g_value)) { // if current value doesn't equal to guess value
                  remove_name.add(p_name);
             }
       }                 
   }
}

for(String r_name : remove_name) {
   people.remove(r_name);
}
```

EDIT:

Problem: I know I can use iterator, like all the other questions ask in stackoverflow, but I don't know how to loop twice to get into people_attributes hashmap.

Comment: Sorry, I have closed your question since we already have an identical one here. If you meant something more specific, please edit the post to clarify it, and we will reopen it.

Comment: @Andrew I can't get my head around how to loop `while(it.hasNext())` twice to get the people_attributes hashmap

Comment: what did you mean by "twice"? writing two consecutive `while` statements?